# The word “Reichskabinettspaleis“

Tags: word-choice

The word *Reichskabinettspaleis* is used in [this book](http://books.google.tk/books?id=OVtKS9DCN0kC&pg=PA182#v=onepage&q&f=true).

Is this word correct? shouldn’t it be *Reichskanzlerpalais* instead?

Here's an image that covers way more than needed:

[image]

Comment: change .tk in the link given to .fr .de .rs .com etc and test again.

Comment: @hellcode: No. btw, The sentence is: *Cuno met with his cabinet and the trade union officials in Reichskabinettspaleis in Berlin*. I could not find *Reichskabinettspaleis* anywhere else.

Comment: _Palais_ would be correct indeed, _paleis_ seems to be a typo. _Palast_ is more common in general, with _Palais_ only being used in proper names for royal residences located within city borders.

Answer (score 2):

The word "Reichskabinettspaleis" doesn't exist, because "paleis" is not german (maybe dutch or belgian).

Wilhelm Cuno was a "Reichskanzler" in Germany (22.11.1922-12.08.1923).
The Cabinet was called "Reichskabinett", but the building in Berlin (Wilhelmstraße 77) where they could have met is "Reichskanzlerpalais" (or "Reichskanzler-Palais") also known as "Reichskanzlei" (see http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichskanzlei).

Here is an example for "Reichskanzler-Palais" (1925, but without Cuno):
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bundesarchiv_Bild_102-02063,_Reichskabinett_Luther_I.jpg

Comment: In German you can make compounds by adding a hyphen or simply writing them together. So Reichskanzlerpalais and Reichskanzler-Palais are the same. And you didn't answer the question... And palais sounds French to me...

Comment: @hellcode Well, palais is palace, paleis is palace. So the difference is two words with the same meaning. It could also be 'Reichskabinettpalast'. And furthermore I think the editors made some typos...

Comment: @hellcode you totally ignore the '-kanzler-' '-kabinett-' part. And I don't understand the one with 'Brotmaschine'

Comment: [Paleis](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleis) is dutch for [palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palace). In german, [Palais](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palais#Moderne_Verwendung_des_Begriffs) was often used to denote official representative buildings, like the seat of government. **Reichskabinettspaleis** is obviously a typo.